# Opacity in PDF not rendered the same between Adobe Reader and TeXworks

Tags: tikz-trees, viewers, transparency

When producing a PDF from the following example using `pdflatex`, I get different results between Adobe Reader and TeXworks. I think this is a bug in the way that Reader handles opacity/transparency.

My goal is to have just a small space between the black node and each edge (like how TeXworks is rendering it), and the way I'm doing that is by setting a black fill and `color=transparent`/`opacity=0` edge for each node.

Can anyone suggest a nice workaround to get consistent results? I have many trees I am trying to render that suffer from this issue and I would like to have the space between the edge and node be transparent rather than white.

Maybe I can draw fully transparent nodes, and then draw a smaller black node on top of each of these. Can this be automated as part of the `state` syle? Or can I set a gap between the start and end of every edge? (How would I do this?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{lts}=[
  state/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,line width=2pt,draw opacity=0,color=transparent,fill=black},
  edge from parent/.style={-stealth,draw},
  obs/.style={edge from parent/.style={-stealth,draw,very thick}},
]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[lts]
      \node[state] {}
        child[obs] {node[state] {}
        edge from parent node {}}
        child[obs] {node[state] {}
        edge from parent node {}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comparing the rendering in TeXworks to Reader:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw3zu.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: BTW Off topic :TeXworks uses [poppler library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) for pdf rendering like many [poppler based free pdf readers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)#cite_note-pop-wiki-6) and TeXmaker switched to [qpdf library](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net), Hence different rendering happens on each viewer.

Comment: @texenthusiast: I doubt that they use qpdf for the _rendering_.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Correction my earlier comment: sorry it is [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) instead of qpdf. Even it uses Poppler support but with CUPS for printing support and the Qt toolkit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `draw=none` instead of `color=transparent` seems to properly display it in Acrobat. The image on the left is the one with `color=transparent`, and the one on the right is with `draw=none`as viewed in Acrobat:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{lts}=[
  state/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,line width=2pt,draw opacity=0,color=transparent,fill=black},
  edge from parent/.style={-stealth,draw},
  obs/.style={edge from parent/.style={-stealth,draw,very thick}},
]

\tikzset{MyState/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,line width=2pt,draw opacity=0,draw=none,fill=black}}
\tikzset{MyObs/.style={edge from parent/.style={-stealth,draw,very thick}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[lts]
      \node[state] {}
        child[obs] {node[state] {}
        edge from parent node {}}
        child[obs] {node[state] {}
        edge from parent node {}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[MyState] {}
        child[MyObs] {node[MyState] {}
        edge from parent node {}}
        child[MyObs] {node[MyState] {}
        edge from parent node {}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than I thought I could get. In fact, I can just remove `draw` from `state`. Thanks!